# Storefront child theme still load parent CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, storefront

I have a problem with the Storefront child theme.
I created a Storefront child theme like they suggest here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/set-up-and-use-a-child-theme/

The child theme works fine, I can write my CSS, write my code inside functions.php and override template files, but the child theme still loads the parent theme CSS.

How I can create a child theme without the parent's CSS loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these functions to your child theme's functions.php.

This code will disable the loading of the Storefront default CSS.

Source: https://github.com/stuartduff/storefront-child-theme

```
/**
 * Storefront automatically loads the core CSS even if using a child theme as it is more efficient
 * than @importing it in the child theme style.css file.
 *
 * Uncomment the line below if you'd like to disable the Storefront Core CSS.
 *
 * If you don't plan to dequeue the Storefront Core CSS you can remove the subsequent line and as well
 * as the sf_child_theme_dequeue_style() function declaration.
 */

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sf_child_theme_dequeue_style', 999 );

/**
 * Dequeue the Storefront Parent theme core CSS
 */
function sf_child_theme_dequeue_style() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'storefront-style' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'storefront-woocommerce-style' );
}
```

Also, you can disable the WooCommerce standard stylesheets,

Source: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/disable-the-default-stylesheet/

```
/**
 * Set WooCommerce image dimensions upon theme activation
 */
// Remove each style one by one

add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', 'jk_dequeue_styles' );

function jk_dequeue_styles( $enqueue_styles ) {
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-general'] );    // Remove the gloss
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-layout'] );     // Remove the layout
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-smallscreen'] );    // Remove the smallscreen optimisation
    return $enqueue_styles;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that with the time since this answer Storefront's style sheet handle has chenged? This solution is not working for me. The parent theme style sheet keeps loading. :(

Comment: FYI @NilSuria - I've only just come across this issue myself, but if you're still interested my answer should do it for you! :-)

Answer (score 2):

As of [Storefront 2.5.8](https://developer.woocommerce.com/2020/07/06/storefront-2-5-8-release-notes/), released [07 July 2020](https://github.com/woocommerce/storefront/releases/tag/version%2F2.5.8), the means by which to dequeue the Storefront parent theme stylesheet/s have necessarily changed due to Pull request [#1369](https://github.com/woocommerce/storefront/pull/1369).

This commit establishes the Storefront stylesheet's (`handle-name` | *path/to/file.css*):

- `storefront-style` | *wp-content/themes/storefront/style.css* and
- `storefront-icons` | *wp-content/themes/storefront/assets/css/base/icons.css*

as explicit dependencies of `storefront-woocommerce-style` | *wp-content/themes/storefront/assets/css/woocommerce/woocommerce.css*.

This change was made so that child theme's could define `storefront-woocommerce-style` as a dependency, without the risk of breaking the ordering of other Storefront stylesheets, and without the need for setting a higher priority to that enqueued dependency to mitigate such breakages - per Issue [#1299](https://github.com/woocommerce/storefront/issues/1299).

Due to this dependency, any attempt to simply dequeue the `storefront-style` stylesheet (or `storefront-icons`) now will not work (no matter the priority set). You must first redefine/reset the dependencies of `storefront-woocommerce-style`, then with a high priority, any removed dependencies can be dequeued.

Per the below example;

1. First enqueue the woocommerce style with only the icons as a dependency,
2. Then enqueue your child style, and
3. Lastly the storefront style is dequeued.

In this example I have deliberately queued my child style after woocommerce, as I have overridden some woocommerce styles within my own (*if an even lower priority was needed - I could put it in the* `dequeue_styles` *function instead*). If this is wasn't the case, and my child style was simply a direct replacement for the storefront style, I could have simply made it another dependency of woocommerce, with the icons styles - `array( 'storefront-child-style', 'storefront-icons' )`. Or if your child style has replaced both the woocommerce and storefront styles, remove all dependencies from woocommerce, then make the icons a dependency of your child style, then remove woocommerce along with the storefront style. Etc, etc, etc... adjusting it Ad infinitum, according to your specific needs.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles' );
function enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'storefront-woocommerce-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/woocommerce/woocommerce.css', array( 'storefront-icons' ), $storefront_version );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'storefront-child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', '', $storefront_version );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_styles', 99 );
function dequeue_styles() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'storefront-style' );
}
```